# page background wont change after .onclick ??

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get the background color of a page to change based on user input. I've made a form in HTML to ask for the name of the person and their age. I have an inline script (just because I want to see if any changes make it work) but I can't seem to get anything to happen. I know this is super basic but any help would be appreciated.

```
<form name="frmNameAge" id="frmNameAge" method="get" action="">

<table id="formTable">

<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" max="50" name="txtName" id="name" />

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><input type="text" max="10" name="txtAge" id="age" /></td>
```

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="button" name="btnSubmit"    value="Submit" id="button"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>     

</div>
<script>

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
var strColor = prompt("Enter your favorite color.");

}

function changeBackgroundColor(strColor) {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = strColor;
}



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the function that changes the color, therefore you never passed it the value you received from the prompt

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    var strColor = prompt("Enter your favorite color.");
    changeBackgroundColor(strColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem begins with scope.

To solve the issue is to either make the variable `var strColor` global or continue making your variable private and pass the value to the `changeBackgroundColor` function.

```
//global variable solution

var strColor;
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
  strColor = prompt("Enter your favorite color.");
}

function changeBackgroundColor(strColor) {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = strColor;
}

//Private variable 

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    var strColor = prompt("Enter your favorite color.");
    changeBackgroundColor(strColor);
}
```

I recommend reading this tutorial in your leisure time if you wish to find out more.

Link - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not calling the "changeBackgroundColor" on prompt OK click.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/1cL03mxb/

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frmNameAge" id="frmNameAge" method="get" action="">

<table id="formTable">

<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" max="50" name="txtName" id="name" />

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><input type="text" max="10" name="txtAge" id="age" /></td>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="button" name="btnSubmit"    value="Submit" id="button"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
  var strColor = prompt("Enter your favorite color.");
  if ( strColor != null) {
    changeBackgroundColor(strColor)
  }

}

function changeBackgroundColor(strColor) {
  document.body.style.background = strColor;
}
```